# Smooth sliding in/out outer columns on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three columns, and I want the outer two to slide out on refresh smoothly, and then when the mouse enters left/right edge, specific column slides back.

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3362xu89/

This is the jQuery code:

```
var toggleEdges = function(width) {
                var end = true;
                var slideOutLeftEdge = function() {
                    $('.leftAnchor').animate({width: '0px'}, 1000, function() {
                        $('.leftAnchor').hide();
                        end = true;
                    });
                };
                var slideInLeftEdge = function() {
                    $('.leftAnchor').show();
                    $('.leftAnchor').animate({width: width + 'px'}, 1000, function() {
                        end = true;
                    });
                };
                var slideOutRightEdge = function() {
                    $('.rightAnchor').animate({width: '0px'}, 1000, function() {
                        $('.rightAnchor').hide();
                        end = true;
                    });
                };
                var slideInRightEdge = function() {
                    $('.rightAnchor').show();
                    $('.rightAnchor').animate({width: width + 'px'}, 1000, function() {
                        end = true;
                    });
                };

                slideOutLeftEdge();
                slideOutRightEdge();
                $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
                    if (event.pageX > width) {
                        if (end) {
                            end = false;
                            slideOutLeftEdge();
                        }
                    }
                    if (event.pageX < 10) {
                        if (end) {
                            end = false;
                            slideInLeftEdge();
                        }
                    }
                    if (event.pageX < window.innerWidth - width) {
                        if (end) {
                            end = false;
                            slideOutRightEdge();
                        }
                    }
                    if (event.pageX > window.innerWidth - 10) {
                        if (end) {
                            end = false;
                            slideInRightEdge();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            toggleEdges(500);
```

This works really bad - it leaves about 100px wide div when the animation is finished. Sometimes the hover is not catched on the website. And besides, what's most annoying, it can stop working or start stuttering when there is another javascript code doing something on the website.

What's wrong?

Comment: Try to use transform:translate property to animate them. Changing the geometry(in your case the width) of an element causes reflows/layouts and can result in stuttering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
jsfiddle.net/3362xu89/2/
```

Note that I haven't provided you a full solution. I leave the sliding in up to you.

P.S. you will have to remove the classes when you want to add new ones.